# correct use of path in win2008

Tags: windows, delphi

I have an application in Delphi 5 and up right now works very well in a workgroup network. but recently installed a win 2008 server and active directory and the problem is that now I can not access files on Win Server 2008. I found that the problem is that I give the path is composed of the IP of the server and the file name. something is not configured properly in win2008 or I'm not addressed either the name of the file?

example

```
type 192.168.0.200:C:\aaa010101aaa_csd_01.key
The file name, directory, or volume label sintax is incorrect.
```

original code does not work

```
OpenSSL.exe pkcs8 -inform DER -in "192.168.0.200:C:\SISTEMA NIUX\aaa010101aaa_CSD_01.key" -passin pass:a0123456789 -out "192.168.0.200:C:\SISTEMA NIUX\pkey.key.pem"
```

Comment: Since it doesn't work with the `type` or `openssl` commands, either, then it's clearly not just a problem in your program. This is not a programming question. It's a question of how to configure your server's network drives. I've voted to move this to Server Fault.

Comment: Since you have clearly typed `sintax` yourself how can we be sure that your error message is indeed correctly transcribed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a valid file path for Windows of any version. You need to first make sure that C: is shared and that you're logged in with a valid account on that machine, and then use a proper UNC filename. Presuming that `C:\SISTEMA NIUX` is the folder the file is in, the proper path to the file would be something like:

```
"\\192.168.0.200\C\SISTEMA NIUX\aaa010101aaa_csd_01.key"
```

Note that if there isn't a specific share set up, you'll need to use the default admnistrative share, which means adding a dollar sign (`$`) after the drive letter:

```
"\\192.168.0.200\C$\SISTEMA NIUX\aaa010101aaa_csd_01.key"
```

Comment: +1 for the double slasshes in front. That caught my eye immediately as well. The dollar sign (C$) is just how _Windows_ sets up default shares for all drives. It probably is not accessible (rights have not been assigned) and unnecessary when you share C outright. Also the folder name somehow suggests a *NIX system to me :-)

Comment: @Marjan: My first thought was *NIX, too, but the tags specifically said "windows" and "delphi". You're right about the `$`, of course; that's for the default administrative share, and not for directly shared drives. That's why I said "something like this", and not "exactly like this". :)